# Why is `operator[]' needed when 'operator double*` seems to do the job

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

`operator[]` seems superfluous since `operator double*` seems to be enough.

Here is my code:

```cpp
struct CStandardData
{
  inline operator double* () { return m_standardData; }
  //inline double& operator [] (size_t ix) { return m_standardData[ix]; }
  size_t  m_standardDataRefCnt{ 0 };
  double m_standardData[1];
} sd;
```

I use `sd` in all kinds of different situations including `double *a = sd`, `sd[x] = 5.0`, `sd[x] >= sd[y]`, etc.  and regardless whether I have the `operator []` commented out or defined, the code seems to work correctly.

In what situations would it be necessary to have `operator []`?

I probably should have added a bit of context:

I used the internal data `double sd[]`, which was dynamically allocated, throughout a large base of code >5000 lines.  Then I needed to add allocation reference counting to this double array, because of a need to copy the object it was in, and pass a copy to the user (the `double sd[]` is >10000 elements so I did not want extra copies made).  This is the scheme that I devised to do that without having to modify the vast base of code using it, but was not sure if omitting `operator []` could lead to any problems.

Comment: Necessary?  None.  There are always alternatives, for example you could use `double at(size_t ix) const { return m_standardData[ix]; }`.  Relying on the implicit conversion is a matter of personal preference or team guidelines.  I prefer to be explicit than implicit, but that is by no means standard practice in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In what situations would it be necessary to have operator []?

In situations when you want your object act as a container but not a pointer. For example this code:

```
MyContainer cnt;
if( cnt ) // something
```

will compile if you define `operator double *`, but I do not want this code to compile in general for my container, because it does not make any sense.

Comment: `operator double*()` also allows things like `void* ptr = cnt;` Which means `MyContainer` objects can be passed to any function that takes a `void*`. It also allows expressions like `cnt + 42`. So `operator double*()` allows more things that what are actually needed. `operator []` only allows exactly what's needed, and no more.

Answer (score -1):

`sd[x] = 5.0` does not have a context for compiler to apply implicit user-defined conversion of `CStandardData` to `double *` prior to invoking `operator []`. If such a conversion is performed explicitly then there will be no need for overloading `operator []`: `static_cast<double *>(sd)[x]`

Also overloading `operator []` seems like a good idea anyway because it will allow you to verify that passed index is valid.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't have sufficient context?  I'm seeing an implicit user-defined conversion of CStandardData to double* for `sd[x] = 5.0;` with C++17, using clang.  If I change it to `explicit operator double* () { return m_standardData; }` that prevents the implicit conversion, as one would expect.  An alternative to the static_cast is `sd.operator double*()[x] = 5.0;`

Comment: Doesn't the expression `sd[x];` have enough context to call the implicit user-defined conversion operator all by itself?

Comment: @Eljay There is no requirement for compiler to consider possible user-defined conversions that would, if applied, make follow up operator or function invocation valid. That is `sd[x]` means invoke `operator []` on `sd` object, just like `sd.foo()` means invoke function `foo` on `sd` object. It for me it seems like a good thing because lookup rules in C++ are already quite messy.

Comment: [over.built]/16 says otherwise.

Comment: @T.C. That part only states candidate operator existence, which does not make any implicit conversion necessary.

Comment: I'm not going to quote chapter and verse on how overload resolution works for operators and how the built-in candidates behave. You can look it up yourself instead of making stuff up.

Comment: @T.C. Built in candidates are not even considered here.

Comment: @VTT Built-in candidates are always considered for every operator usage, if at least one operand has a class or enumeration type. This answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @VTT Or actually, [over.match.oper]/4 does say no temporaries or implicit conversions for the left side of an assignment expression, and the section has a few other custom rules for various operators. But the section has no such limitations for `operator[]`.